# Unnest array of arrays

Tags: postgresql, array, set-returning-functions

In my parameterized query I have to unnest arrays with 1 dimension and 2 dimensions:

```
$1: ARRAY['id1', 'id2']
$2: ARRAY[ARRAY['tag1'], ARRAY['tag2']]
```

I tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, tags)
SELECT * FROM UNNEST ($1::text[], $2::text[][])
```

But got this error:

> ```
> column "tags" is of type text[] but expression is of type text
> ```

I want the result of `SELECT * FROM UNNEST ...` to be 2 rows:

```
'id1', ARRAY['tag1']
'id2', ARRAY['tag2']
```

Answer (score 2):

To unnest 1-dimensional arrays from N-dimensional arrays, I suggest this custom function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_nd_1d(a ANYARRAY, OUT a_1d ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS SETOF ANYARRAY
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOREACH a_1d SLICE 1 IN ARRAY a_2d LOOP
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

See:

- [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8142998/939860)

Then to achieve your desired result:

```
SELECT unnest(a1), unnest_nd_1d(a2)
FROM  (
   SELECT '{id1,id2}'::text[]
        , '{{tag1},{tag2}}'::text[]
   ) t(a1, a2);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=482eedfd45a37a494cae76e74af72d8f)*

About those multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)
- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27854382/939860)

Your use of `text[][]` indicates a **misunderstanding**. Postgres does not enforce array dimensions. See:

- [Use string[][] with ngpsql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34315117/939860)
- [Mapping PostgreSQL text[][] type and Java type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10745524/939860)